# WSO2 ESB is throwing exception when I make a REST request with Accept header value = application/json

Tags: proxy, wso2, esb

I have created a proxy service in the ESB that calls a REST service in the backend.
When I test the proxy service with a REST client and pass Accept header with application/json WSO2 ESB is throwing an exception

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-08-14 16:45:17,219] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Error while building message {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1081]
Message: The element type "HR" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</HR>".
```

It works perfectly with application/xml value.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a little bit more? Like an example request?

Comment: POST /services/Location HTTP/1.1
Via: 1.1 ISOPROXYP01
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 172.16.133.56:10000
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 215

Comment: and this is the request body:  {"ADDRESS":{"HomeAddress":{"HomeCity":"Boise","HomeFailLevel":"0","HomeState":"ID","HomeStreetName":"HAZEL","HomeStreetNum":"2900","HomeStreetType":"ST","HomeZip":"83703"}},"CommOrPers":"C","ProductName":"PPCXW"}  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the service is having trouble generating the json (`ParseError at [row, col]: [1.1081]`). Works with XML because it seems that the XML is ok. The `< hr >` is an HTML tag, then you may be missing a "scape" CDATA or something like this. The service is yours or is a third party? If it ia a third party, probably the service only supports XML return. If it's yours, please show us more details of the conversion to json.